# Regex matches only the first two of many possibilities in a matching group

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I've noticed that the c++11 regex is only "considering" the first two choices in a matching group that contains 4 choices. The regex is correct according to regex101 and if I change the order of the elements in the matching group, the first two always get recognized but not the following ones.
The code is pretty straightforward, is there something that I missed ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::regex staticFilesMatcher(".*\\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript | std::regex_constants::icase);
    if (std::regex_match("test.ico", staticFilesMatcher))
        std::cout << "ICO file recognized" << std::endl;
    if (std::regex_match("test.jpg", staticFilesMatcher))
        std::cout << "JPG file recognized" << std::endl;
    if (std::regex_match("test.png", staticFilesMatcher))
        std::cout << "PNG file recognized" << std::endl;
    if (std::regex_match("test.gif", staticFilesMatcher))
        std::cout << "GIF file recognized" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Weirdly, the output is

```
ICO file recognized
JPG file recognized

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.002 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Thanks for any help that could get me to find the solution to this.

Comment: It worked fine for me.  I just did a copy and paste of your code and got correct result.  Oh, and I compiled on Linux using g++.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Your code worked fine in [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/CcDdSt) and in [VC online](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)

Comment: VS2013 and it's working

Comment: The command used to compile is `g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11  -c /home/hilnius/development/tests/regex/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/regex obj/Debug/main.o`
and the compiler `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you are using GCC 4.8.2. But [`regex` was not implemented until GCC 4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html). If you can't upgrade your compiler, you'll have to use `boost.regex`.